# Moving to next array value failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I created a js quiz. The questions are stored in a jquery array. However, clicking on next will not proceed to the next array value. How to fix this?

```
function nextQuestion() {

    submt = true;
    $('#explanation').empty();
    $('#question').append(quiz[currentquestion]['question']).html();
    if (quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[
        currentquestion]['image'] != "") {
        if ($('#question-image').length == 0) {
            $(document.createElement('img')).addClass(
                'question-image').attr('id',
                'question-image').attr('name', 'anscho').attr(
                'src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr(
                'alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion][
                    'question'
                ])).insertAfter('#question');
        } else {
            $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[
                currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt',
                htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])
            );
        }
    } else {
        $('#question-image').remove();
    }
    addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
    setupButtons();
}
```

Comment: Where you used `++`?

Comment: Where does `currentquestion` get incremented?

Comment: function processQuestion() {
        //alert(choice);
        currentquestion++;
        //alert(currentquestion);
        $("#submitbutton").hide();
        if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
            endQuiz();
        } else {
            nextQuestion();
        }
    }

Comment: Please update your question and put relevant codes there

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Thanks to Johnny Mopp for pointing out that `currentquestion` should be incremented. Thanks!!!